# Create Template based email via SOAP

Tags: api, soap

Is there a way we can create a template based email using SOAP API?

Comment: Are you trying to create an email template, or send an email via a template?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a specific method for sending emails via the SOAP API - [sendEmail()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm).

You pass it an instance of [SingleEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm#SingleEmailMessageTitle), which inherits the `templateId` from `BaseEmail`. The EmailTemplate ID will start with the `00X` key prefix.